# Composite keys with AUTO_INCREMENT and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP working together

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

Similarly to many other questions about composite keys with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, I am receiving the following error:

`Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

What I'm doing is making a history trail of all changes in the table. Every time a change is made, a new row is inserted with a new timestamp, leaving previous modifications untouched.

My DDL in concern is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personnel;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personnel
(
    modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ...

    PRIMARY KEY (modified, id),
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I presume that I'm getting this error because I am using both `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`. So is there a way to resolve this *without* making PHP do the timestamp generation (so my model can just insert as if it were any other table, letting the controller do the dirty work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's error message has more to be desired...

The autoincrementing column has to be at the beginning of an index. In your case you need to add another index  - `KEY id(id)`.